# how to start couchdb lucene and integrate it with bigcouch

Tags: java, lucene, couchdb, bigcouch

i want to using couchdb-lucene as full text search,
but i can't run it...

i got this error

> ls: cannot access lib/*.jar: No such file or directory Exception in
>   thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/github/rnewson/couchdb/lucene/Main Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.github.rnewson.couchdb.lucene.Main    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266) Could not find
>   the main class: com.github.rnewson.couchdb.lucene.Main. Program will
>   exit.

and how to integrate it with bigcouch..?

i can't start it so i can't try to integrate it with bigcouch...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you build the zip file, unpack it, and run the startup script from the bin/ folder?

https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene/blob/master/README.md

Comment: where is the actual location of "lib" folder, because i find "run" file in src/main/bin... and in the "bin" folder there are 2 file, "kill_ppid" and "run"... from error above, i think there should be "lib" folder in the "bin" folder

Comment: It sounds like you haven't built and unpacked the zip file, please follow the procedure in the README ('mvn' then unzip the .zip file in the target folder and run 'bin/run' from *inside* the unpacked zip file).

Answer (score 0):

I built the Lucene from the source. Did this on Windows 7, probably works on other OSes aswell. On windows Install Maven and add Mavens bin folder path to environment variable PATH (on Linux it should be installed by aptitude). You build Lucene in command prompt (open the prompt after you install maven and add the bin path) and go to the folder where the Lucene src is. On the same folder you can see a file named 'pom.xml'. Execute command 'mvn clean install'. It takes a while to build and it loads a lot of dependencies from the internet. Finally uou get a dist.zip in a target folder (folder created when building). Take the zip, unpack it and take the libraries (jar files in the builds 'lib' folder). Copy them to to Lucenes 'lib' folder. Lucene should work now.